# Automation testing for react native app for both android and iOS platform

Tags: automation, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, react-native-ios

As per project requirement, need to do automation testing on the Reactnative app for Android/iOS platforms. I have seen many frameworks available such as appium, Cavy, Detox.
Need help in the selection of framework for reactnative app testing.

Have appium automation(with Java) experience for Android application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on developing and maintaining Cavy, so if you have any particular questions regarding Cavy as a solution, I'd be happy to help. Just pop any issues/questions on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/pixielabs/cavy/issues).

We're in the process of moving all our documentation to [our new site](https://cavy.app/), but it does include a comparison with Detox in the [FAQs](https://cavy.app/docs/faq) that you may find useful :)